# How to convert text with things like %C3%A0

Tags: html, excel, text

I have many list of names with things like `%C3%A0` which I believe stands for a with an apostrophe.

`M%C3%A0rius Torres` should be `Marius Torres`.

But the problems is that there are many different kinds of these and I cannot change them manually anymore. There are about 13,000 unique names.

How can I convert it into their correct names in excel?

As a reference, I queried many names in wikipedia database. [Here is the link](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%2a%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A?p%20a%0D%0A%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person%3E%20.%0D%0A?p%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced%3E%20?influenced.%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: http://php.net/urldecode

Comment: You have **php** in the tags, but say **excel** in the question. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping for either one that can do this job automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names have most likely been URL encoded. This is done to anything that is included in an URL. For example, if I try to search for " it's " on Google, my browser goes to the address https://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=it%27s. As you can see, the " it's " has been changed to " it%27s ".

All that you need to do in PHP to undo this is to put the string through the urldecode() function. You'd do the following:

$string = "M%C3%A0rius Torres";

$decoded = urldecode($string);

echo $decoded;

That should give you the decoded string. Read more about the urldecode() function at https://www.php.net/urldecode.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, like [Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word), you should be able to use "find"/"find & select" followed by "replace".

You can also "sort and filter" to group things.

Both in top right hand corner of the Home page in Excel.

Comment: I've been doing it in excel, but I realized that there are many different kinds of them. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your text is URL encoded. Since you have `php` as one of your tags, I'm assuming the output goes through some form of PHP processing. In that case, you'll want to use the `urldecode` function. Documentation can be found [here](https://www.php.net/urldecode).